# Safari Add to Homescreen adds semicolon to url -> 404

Tags: php, ios, safari

Hit there,

my customers are telling me, that on iOS Safari the following problem is appearing.

When they add my site to their homescreen, the url ends with a ';' so the url is like: https://mysite/index.php;

This results in a 404. If I delete the ; it works fine.

What can I change to get this working?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are they adding the shortcut to their Home Screen? Using the inbuilt function in safari or via some code on your site?

Comment: they are using the inbuilt safari function